# Matlab Buttord returning Wn > 1 why?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I am new to matlab and signals course, but i have a homework stating that I have to design a DT filter for Butterworth.
I have these given parameters:

- The noisy signal is stored in the variable noisy and was sampled at
  44100 (fs) Hz.

  1. Passband edge: 2500 Hz.
  2. Stopband edge: 4000 Hz.
  3. Maximum gain in the passband Gpbmax: 40 dB.
  4. Minimum gain in the passband Gpbmin: 37 dB.
  5. Maximum gain in the stopband Gsbmax: −55 dB.

What I did:

```
[n, Wn] = buttord(2500*2*pi, 4000*2*pi, 3, 55, 's'); 
% Wn here is 1.5989e+04, I couldn't execute this without the 's' option.

[b, a] = butter(n, Wn)
The cutoff frequencies must be within the interval of (0,1).
```

Any answer please ?

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2557-lowpass-digital-butterworth-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the `'s'` option, `Wn` is returned in rad/s, see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/buttord.html). To use it with `butter`, you need to normalise by the sampling frequency, or don't use the `'s'` option:

```
fs = 2*pi*44100;
[b, a] = butter(n, Wn/fs);
```

or use `butter` with the `'s'` option as well:

```
[b,a] = butter(n,Wn,'s');
```